# Laplace transform using partial fractions

Tags: laplace-transform

I want to know how does $\dfrac{1}{(s^2+1)^2}$ is equal to $\mathcal{L}\{\sin t - t\cos t\}$ because my professor told me to use the partial fractions method but I'm not getting the exact answer.

Comment: What is your approach. How are you handling the $t\cos t$ part. Do you have a method for finding the Laplace transform of functions of the type $t\,f(t)$?

Comment: What answer do you get? Is it different by a constant multiple?

Comment: Note that this problem does not require partial fraction decomposition since $\dfrac{1}{(s^2+1)^2}$ is already a partial fraction and cannot be decomposed any further. You need to use the Laplace transforms $\mathcal{L}\{\sin t\},\mathcal{L}\{\cos t\}$ and $\mathcal{L}\{t\,f(t)\}$ which give two rational fractions in $s$ which you need to add together to get the result which will differ slightly from the one you stated.

Answer (score 1):

For any $s>0$ we have:
$$ \frac{1}{s^2+1} = \frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{s-i}-\frac{1}{s+i}\right)=\frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-t(s-i)}-e^{-t(s+i)}\,dt\tag{1}$$
or
$$ \frac{1}{s^2+1} = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(t)e^{-ts}\,dt =\mathcal{L}(\sin t)\tag{2}$$
but we also have, by squaring the LHS of $(1)$,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\color{red}{\frac{1}{(s^2+1)^2}}&=&-\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{(s-i)^2}+\frac{1}{(s+i)^2}-\frac{2}{s^2+1}\right)\\&=&-\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{+\infty}te^{-t(s-i)}+t e^{-t(s+i)}-i e^{-t(s-i)}+ie^{-t(s+i)}\,dt\\&=&\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}(\sin t-t\cos t)e^{-ts}\,dt=\color{red}{\mathcal{L}\left(\frac{\sin t-t\cos t}{2}\right)}.\tag{3}\end{eqnarray*}$$
In the opposite direction,
$$\forall s>0,\quad\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin t-t\cos t}{2}e^{-ts}\,dt = \frac{1}{(s^2+1)^2}\tag{4} $$
is easy to prove by integration by parts.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With $\ds{\Re\pars{c} > 0}$ and $\ds{t > 0}$:

\begin{align}
\int_{c - \infty\ic}^{c + \infty\ic}{\expo{ts} \over \pars{s^{2} + 1}^{2}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} & =
\mrm{Res}\pars{\expo{ts} \over \bracks{s^{2} + 1}^{2}}_{\ s\ =\ -\ic} +
\mrm{Res}\pars{\expo{ts} \over \bracks{s^{2} + 1}^{2}}_{\ s\ =\ \ic}
\\[5mm] & =
\partiald{}{s}\bracks{{\expo{ts} \over \pars{s - \ic}^{2}}}_{\ s\ =\ -\ic} +
\partiald{}{s}\bracks{{\expo{ts} \over \pars{s + \ic}^{2}}}_{\ s\ =\ \ic}
\\[5mm] & =
2\,\Re\pars{{1 \over 4}\,\expo{-\ic t}\bracks{-t + \ic}} =
\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{1 \over 2}\bracks{-t\cos\pars{t} + \sin\pars{t}}}
\end{align}